# Android and Eclipse - a problem

Tags: android, eclipse, svn

I'm a newbie with Eclipse and Android. I have a legacy project from an
SVN repository which I could import and use under Eclipse Helios. Also
changes inside and outside Eclipse are synchronized fine with the SVN.

Now the problem: The project structure consists of a root directory,
referring to a src path, which exists outside the root (i.e. on the
same level as the root of the project is). I guess this has been
arranged by the designer, because the src part has been referenced
from different java projects for different platforms. I think this is
not such a bad idea.

However: Whatever I do I can't make Eclipse and SVN synchronize
changes on files located in this "outer" directory. What do I have to
do in order to make both aware of the outer parts, w/o being forced to
change the file/dir structure completely?

Kind regards

Comment: I think the solution might be clearer if you shared specific details about the directory structure. Everything in an Eclipse project is contained under its own directory in the workspace, so there should be no reason why the directory in question can't be set as a source directory.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your description you did the following ?

1. You Removed the src folder created by eclipse during the first check out.
2. You create a linked src folder  (when you created it, instead of just accepting all the defaults, you opened the "advanced" dialog box and checked the radio button saying `Link...(Linked Folder)` and you filled in the location where you wanted that "outer" src folder to be located).
3. You updated from the repository.
4. But when you look at the updated folders, the src that has been updated is *really* under the root rather than the one you have shifted away.

Can you confirm my understanding ?

If not, then you might try the procedure outlined above.

Unless there are twists in the ADT I don't know about (a little bit like in hierarchical maven projects where you can "export as Maven subproject"), I cannot see any other scenario that would lead to the problem you describe.

Comment: Hi Alain, thanks for your response. I did "svn checkout" and got two folders: The folder containing the project and (at the same level) the shared source folder. This is embedded as "linked folder". Now I'm importing the project into Eclipse. Eclipse recognizes the project as "under source control", but doesn't do that for the external shared source folder.

Comment: BTW: If I hit "properties" on the linked folder in the project and then "SVN" Eclipse excepts with "0x000014: Resource is inaccessible or not under source control". I can also not put the files again under source control...

Comment: @neil. Does it have a .svn subfolder ?  Or is the .svn folder in the src that's under the root ?

Comment: OK. Seems I got it. Re-checked out, now not from the command line, but from within Eclipse, and it works now. Thanks

Comment: @neil. I did not suspect you where using the command line svn interface.  Yes the "Team" context menu is the way to go for all things having to do with Source Code Management.  Also, you can delete your additional answer (I guess you intended to add a comment and I actually only took notice now).  On StackOverflow owners can remove their own answers regardless of their privilege levels. thx.